# Variavel undefined PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Quero fazer um formulario aonde eu envio por meio do ajax, o valor do input e, no codigo php, faço uma consulta no banco de dados e retorno todos os valores dessa consulta para a pagina.

Por algum motivo que não estou conseguindo compreender, meu codigo php esta sendo chamada através do ajax mas minha variável que mandei via ajax está retornando indefinida.

Meu ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#alterar-anotacao').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id_ano =  $("#id_anotacao_alterar").val();
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '../painel/php/buscar_anotacao.php',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#btn-alterar-anotacao").val("Carregando...");
                },
                data: {id_ano: id_ano},
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    $("#id_anotacao_alterar").val('');
                    $('#titulo-alterar').focus();
                    $(".resultado-anotacao-alterar").html(msg);
                    $("btn-alterar-anotacao").val("Enviar anotação");
                }
            });
    })
</script>
```

Meu php:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; iso-8859-1');

 include ('../../config/config.php');

 $id_ano = $_POST['id_ano'];

 $get_info = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `anotacoes` WHERE `id`=?");
 $get_info->execute(array($id_ano));

 $qtd = $get_info->rowCount();
 if($qtd>0){

    while ($row = $get_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $anotacao = $row['anotacao'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#titulo-anotacao-alterar').val("<?php echo $titulo;?>");
    $('#status-anotacao-alterar').val( "<?php echo $status;?>");
    $('#txt-anotacao-alterar').val("<?php echo $anotacao;?>");
</script>
<?php } ?>
 <?php }else{?>
    <script>
        alert('Nao foram encontrados registros com este número.');
        $("#id_anotacao_alterar").focus();
    </script>
 <?php }?>
```

E o erro que esta vindo para mim:

> Warning: Undefined array key "id_ano" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\PHP-projects\Sistema Transportes\painel\php\buscar_anotacao.php on line 6

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Está dando esse erro, pois no `$_POST` não existe um chave com valor `id_ano`.

Para resolver o erro, você pode tentar alterar o `dataType` de `html` para `json`, pois o `id_ano` está sendo enviado como json.

Fiz algumas melhorias no seu código

```
if(!isset($_POST['id_ano'])){
    echo '<script>
            alert("O id_ano não foi informado.");
            $("#id_anotacao_alterar").focus();
         </script>';
}
$id_ano = $_POST['id_ano'];

$get_info = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `anotacoes` WHERE `id`=?");
$get_info->execute(array($id_ano));

$qtd = $get_info->rowCount();
if($qtd>0){

    $data = $get_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
    $titulo = $dados['titulo'];
    $status = $dados['status'];
    $anotacao = $dados['anotacao'];

    echo '  
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#titulo-anotacao-alterar").val("'. $titulo . '");
        $("#status-anotacao-alterar").val( "'. $status . '");
        $("#txt-anotacao-alterar").val('. $anotacao . ');
        </script>
    ';
} else {
    echo '<script>
        alert("Nao foram encontrados registros com este número.");
        $("#id_anotacao_alterar").focus();
    </script>';
}
```

Comment: Um ponto importante é que se enviar como json a variável $_POST não é preenchida, será necessário recuperar com `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Answer (score -2):

Imagino que esteja ocorrendo um conflito entre o seu objeto enviado no data e  o formato selecionado no `dataType`, por isso sua variável $_POST está vazia.

Uma opção que você tem é utilizar função [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do Jquery.

Veja este exemplo extraído da [documentação do jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

Assim você pode remover o `dataType` e enviar o form serializado diretamente no parâmetro data.

Existem outras abordagens como enviar como json e recuperar com a função abaixo no seu backend:

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```